# What is `#pragma pack` for in network programming?

Tags: c++, pragma-pack

```
 #pragma pack(push)
 #pragma pack(1)
```

I downloaded a tutorial and it has these lines in the header file.
I will appreciate if you guys can provide me any tutorials or references related to this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Microsoft's explanation:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa273913(v=vs.60).aspx

IBM's AIX xlC explanation:

http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/comphelp/v8v101/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.xlcpp8a.doc%2Fcompiler%2Fref%2Frnpgpack.htm

Basically, it determines the byte boundaries that will be used when storing a structure or union.  The push/pop acts as a way to store and retrieve these settings on a stack.

For future reference, you might save yourself some time by searching for the keywords you're asking as about on the web.  All I did to find this information was search for "pragma pack" at http://www.google.com

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Do I need packing if I run the server on linux machine?

Comment: @LCYSoft: see [Gilad Naors answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6353054/what-is-pragma-pack-for-in-network-progamming/6353230#6353230). This is Microsoft specific.

Answer (score 2):

All `#pragma` statements are vendor specific.

This one is Microsoft specific, and describes how much "packing" (in bytes) the compiler can add to `struct`s for better alignment.

The `#pragma pack(push)` simply saves and previous setting in a stack. You can then change the packing conditions for a certain block of code, and later on `#pragma pack(pop)` to restore the previous settings.

Answer (score 1):

It's the MSVC++ specific packing specifier. You can find out exactly what it does from [the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2e70t5y1.aspx).

The packing changes how much padding the compiler is allowed to insert between data members of a given struct (or class) to maintain alignment. In the case of networking code, the `#pragma pack` specifier is probably being used so that a structure can be cast to a `char*` or `void*` to be passed to some network API, to send the entire struct over the network at once.

(Note this is unsafe as different machines have different rules for alignment and byte order; this will only work if both machines on each end of the wire use the same hardware type)